# match a word with leading white space

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following strings in array `@stat`:

```
  r>  10.12.44.0/24                             
  r>  10.11.48.0/24                               
  *>  10.15.49.0/24                              
  r>  10.16.53.0/24                               
  r>  10.14.59.0/24                              
  *>  10.18.63.0/24
```

I want match the one who have "`*>`". Note that there is whitespace before the `*`. I tried using the following, but it didn't work.

```
foreach (@stat) {
    if (/^\s\*\>/) { 
    # do something
    }
}
```

What did I miss?

Comment: try `/^\s*\*\>/` maybe?  That would allow multiple whitespace chars before the *

Comment: That should match, although you don't have to escape `>`. Your input probably does not contain what you think it does.

Comment: thanks much Steve & TLP the issue resolved with "/^\s*\*\>/" without escape ">"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\s` matches one whitespace character. What you posted actually has two leading spaces. Tthe following should do the trick:

```
foreach (@stat) {
    if (/^\s*\*>/) { 
        # do something
    }
}
```

If not, check what's actually in your array more carefully.

```
use Data::Dumper qw( Dumper );

{
    local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
    print(Dumper(\@stat));
}
```